# I need to take the average of 3 columns, row by row and create a new column with these averages in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so i am working on doing some data analysis for a research project. i need to take the average of triplicate samples row by row and create a new column with these results. my dataframe is also 7500 rows long. what would be the most efficient way to do this? have pasted an example of the dataframe below. thank you for the help!

```py
Ratio 350 nm / 330 nm for Cap.1   Ratio 350 nm / 330 nm for Cap.2     
0                             0.682213                          0.669024  
1                             0.683215                          0.668730  
2                             0.687275                          0.669415  
3                             0.692500                          0.668675  
4                             0.689679                          0.670420
```

i have not gotten very far with this as i am new to python, so far this is where i am at.

```py
empty_circularized_nd_avg = df.iloc[0:3].mean(axis = 1)
print(empty_circularized_nd_avg)
```

which gives me the answer i am looking for but i am unsure how to make it go row by row down the column

```
0    0.646248
1    0.647073
2    0.648248
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in one line:

```py
import pandas as pd

# get data
df = pd.read_csv("Documents/dataframe.tsv", sep="\t")

# create average column
df['avg'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

It will create a column containing the average for every set of rows if you just use `df`. If you subset it as you did in your example (`df.iloc[0:3]`), then you'll get `NaN` values for rows not included.